# Eigenvalue of Laplacian on the unit ball $B_1(0)\subset \mathbb R^2$.

Tags: real-analysis, ordinary-differential-equations, partial-differential-equations

> I want to show that if $\lambda<0$, there is always a nontrivial solution for
> \begin{align*}
>             -\Delta u+\lambda u=0,\ &x\in B_1(0)\subset \mathbb{R}^2;     \\ 
>             u=0,\ &x\in\partial B_1(0).     \\ 
> \end{align*}
> i.e. to show that any negative number is an eigenvalue of Laplacian.

**My attempt:**

I put $u(x)=v(r)$ where $r=|x|$, from which it's not hard to derive
\begin{align*}
\Delta u=v''(r)+\frac{1}{r}v'(r)
\end{align*}
And then I want to prove that there exists a solution for
\begin{align*}
    \begin{cases}
        -v''(r)-\frac{1}{r}v'(r) +\lambda v(r)=0,\quad \forall r<1 \\
        v(1)=0
    \end{cases}
\end{align*}
But I got stuck on this ODE. Any hints? Thanks in advance!

Comment: Did you look for a variational form ? You could try to use the Lax-Milgram theorem if you are looking for a weak solution.

Comment: Are you sure that **all** $\lambda<0$ are eigenvalues? The spectrum should be discrete.

Answer (score 0):

Keep the angular coordinate for $v$, that is $u(x,y) = v(r,\theta)$.
$$ \Delta v = \frac{1}{r^2}\frac{\partial^2 v}{\partial \theta^2} + \frac{1}{r}\frac{\partial v}{\partial r} + \frac{\partial^2 v}{\partial r^2} $$
So solving this PDE by separation of variables, i.e. $v(r,\theta)=R(r)\Theta(\theta)$, the eingenvalue equation $-\Delta u +\lambda u = 0$ becomes,
$$ \frac{1}{r^2}R\Theta'' + R''\Theta + \frac{1}{r}R'\Theta - \lambda R\Theta = 0 \quad \Leftrightarrow  \quad \frac{r^2R'' + rR' - r^2\lambda R}{R} = -\frac{\Theta''}{\Theta}. $$

We clearly get the solution $\Theta(\theta) = e^{\pm in^2\theta}$ $(n\in\mathbb{N})$ and the differential equation,
$$ r^2R'' + rR' - (n^2 + r^2\lambda) R = 0 $$
which is called a [Bessel differential equation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bessel_function) and has non trivial solutions if $\lambda<0$ (the Bessel functions).

Comment: True, but the Bessel differential equation comes with the boundary condition $R(1)=0$, which rules out some solutions.

Comment: I mean, I am addressing some concern towards the statement "... has nontrivial solutions if $\lambda <0$". This statement is true, but in the eigenvalue problem we are studying there are boundary conditions. These imply that not all $\lambda <0$ admit a solution. (Actually, the values of $\lambda$ for which there is a solution are related to the zeros of the Bessel functions, and they form a discrete set).

Comment: Yes of course, you're right, the spectrum is discrete also.